# error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token

Tags: c

### a.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int main(){
        s.a = 10;
        printf("\n add : %d \n",add(2,2));
        printf("\n sub : %d \n",sub(2,2));
        printf("\n struct is : %d \n",s.a);
        return 0;
}
```

### b.c :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int a,int b){
        return (a+b);
}
int sub(int a,int b){
        return (a-b);
}
```

### a.h :

```
#ifndef A_HEADER
#define A_HEADER

typedef struct _s{
        int a;
        int b;
}s;

int add(int a,int b);
int sub(int a,int b);

#endif
```

O/p:

```
[root@s new]# ls
a.c  a.h  b.c  include 

[root@s new]# gcc -c a.c -o a.o
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:4: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
a.c:7: error: expected expression before ‘s’
```

I 'm getting an error as above. Couldn't find why the error is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s` is a *type* - you need to declare an *instance* of this type:

```
int main(){
    s my_s;       // my_s is an instance of the struct type `s`
    my_s.a = 10;  // initialise the `a` element of `my_s`
    printf("\n add : %d \n",add(2,2));
    printf("\n sub : %d \n",sub(2,2));
    printf("\n struct is : %d \n",my_s.a); // <<<
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You made `s` is as type specifier using `typedef` in ah.h

```
typedef struct _s{
        int a;
        int b;
}s;
```

and doing

```
s.a = 10; // will causes error
```

Use something

```
s s1;
s1.a = 10 ;
```